# Network manager is causing shutdown and suspend to hang intermittently

Tags: networking, network-manager, suspend, shutdown

I have a bash script which creates a hotspot when the ethernet cable is plugged in, and automatically connects to eduroam otherwise. The problem is that Network Manager and wpa_supplicant sometimes (not always) cause shutdown or suspend to hang. The kernel is waiting for the service to stop for several minutes. Does anyone know how to work around this problem?

```
#!/bin/bash

AP=0
while :;
do
 if nmcli device show enp4s0f1 | grep IP4.ADDRESS ; then
    if [[ AP -eq 0 ]]; then
     nmcli device disconnect wlp3s0
     nmcli connection up 'Hotspot'
     AP=1
    fi
 else
    if [[ AP -eq 1 ]]; then
     nmcli connection down 'Hotspot'
     nmcli connection up 'eduroam'
     AP=0
    fi
 fi
 sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to workaround this wpa_supplicant bug?